# What is the best way to deserialize JSON and put the leaf data into Rc structs?

Tags: json, rust, reference-counting, serde

I have a JSON file with some repeating object structure and strings like below.

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "data": [
            "blih",
            "blah",
            "bloh"
        ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

My best understanding of Rust would be to deserialize the JSON into a set of structs and then copy the data into another set of structs that includes `Rc`:

```rust
// json structs
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ArrayJson {
    array: Vec<DataJson>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct DataJson {
    data: Vec<String>,
}

// rc structs
struct ArrayRc {
    array: Vec<DataRc>,
}

struct DataRc {
    data: Vec<Rc<String>>,
}
```

Is there a way I can *not* create two sets of structs and just one?

**Update:** I believe the `rc` of serde is not what I want as it serializes and deserializes the actual `Rc` `Arc` struct.

> Serializing a data structure containing reference-counted pointers
>   will serialize a copy of the inner value of the pointer each time a
>   pointer is referenced within the data structure. Serialization will
>   not attempt to deduplicate these repeated data.
>
> Deserializing a data structure containing reference-counted pointers
>   will not attempt to deduplicate references to the same data. Every
>   deserialized pointer will end up with a strong count of 1.

I only care about the `Rc` struct on the Rust side, hence why I believe I will need two structs.

Comment: Please more clearly explain why the duplicate ([applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4490163cc52e79df8af4be0a7e3d94d6)) is not valid.

Comment: Specifically, it's not clear what you mean by "as it serializes and deserializes the actual `Rc` `Arc` struct."

Comment: That it serializes and deserializes the `Rc` struct, that is, including the reference count. I just want the memory to be managed by `Rc` struct.

Comment: *including the reference count* — it does not. You can [trivially test that yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dbfe6352f05c1e1437699a9f510d686b).

Comment: To be clear then, is the rc feature enabled in the playground? Is it that by deafult the `Rc` struct is ignored by enabling rc then causes to seralize/deserialize the `Rc` struct?

Comment: Yes, [the `rc` feature is enabled](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/da69e7491da0aed6957956d7e2b165be1ce4a91b/compiler/base/Cargo.toml#L843-L846).

Comment: I think the documentation has confused me and have asked a question about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604346/why-does-serde-not-handle-rc-by-default, but I would agree that this question is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable the `rc` feature of the serde crate, and serde will implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for `Rc` and `Arc`. You can then derive the two traits on your `ArrayRc` and `DataRc` structures.

For deserialize, it will create a new `Rc` with a strong count of 1 for every value it deserializes, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Please search for existing questions that answer newly-asked questions before answering them.

Comment: updated my question. I believe enabling the rc feature is not what I want.