# Why does Serde not support Rc and Arc types by default?

Tags: rust, reference-counting, serde

Please explain the Serde `rc` feature

> Opt into impls for `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>`. Serializing and deserializing
>   these types does not preserve identity and may result in multiple
>   copies of the same data. Be sure that this is what you want before
>   enabling this feature.
>
> Serializing a data structure containing reference-counted pointers
>   will serialize a copy of the inner value of the pointer each time a
>   pointer is referenced within the data structure. Serialization will
>   not attempt to deduplicate these repeated data.
>
> Deserializing a data structure containing reference-counted pointers
>   will not attempt to deduplicate references to the same data. Every
>   deserialized pointer will end up with a strong count of 1.

Why does this feature flag exist and why isn't it default behaviour? What does it mean by

> Serializing and deserializing these types does not preserve identity and may result in multiple copies of the same data

I know that it is related to [Serde issue 194](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/194). The [last message of the issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/194#issuecomment-296187925) says

> If you want to make sure you don't accidentally end up with a derived impl containing an rc, open a clippy issue.

Does the feature flag exist to catch unexpected usages of an `Rc` struct?

Comment: The sentence "may result in multiple copies of the same data" seems understandable to me — what do you find confusing about it?

Comment: Why does it end up with multiple copies? For instance, if it deseralizes a string and then wraps it in an `Rc` struct, there would only be one copy. Where does the multiple copies come from? I can understand it for serializing, as it takes a copy to put in a file buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [Serde issue 194](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/194), the drawbacks of the implementation of deserializing to `Rc` or `Arc` are:

> - Potentially increased memory usage
> - Equality comparison that relies on comparison of address breaks
> - Interior mutability is not reflected in copies

This is echoed in the [feature flag documentation](https://serde.rs/feature-flags.html):

> Serialization will not attempt to deduplicate these repeated data.
>
> Deserializing a data structure containing reference-counted pointers will not attempt to deduplicate references to the same data.

The usual point of an `Rc` or `Arc` is to *share* data. This sharing doesn't happen when deserializing to a struct containing `Rc` or `Arc`. In this example, 5 completely distinct `Rc<str>`s are created with no relation to each other, even though they all have the same content:

```
use std::{rc::Rc, ptr};

fn main() {
    let json = r#"[
        "alpha",
        "alpha",
        "alpha",
        "alpha",
        "alpha"
    ]"#;

    let strings = serde_json::from_str::<Vec<Rc<str>>>(json).unwrap();
    
    dbg!(ptr::eq(strings[0].as_ref(), strings[1].as_ref()));
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:14] ptr::eq(strings[0].as_ref(), strings[1].as_ref()) = false
```

This is especially bad when you have an `Rc<RefCell<_>>` or other type with interior mutability, as you might expect that modifying one of the items modifies *all* of the items.

See also:

- [Is there a way to distingush between different `Rc`s of the same value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37706596/155423)
- [How can I get Serde to allocate strings from an arena during deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51988630/155423)

Comment: Interesting. You example is the exactly the behaviour I would expect - 5 completely distinct `Rc<str>`s. `Rc` does not guarantee uniqueness. If I was looking for uniqueness than I would want to use a Set-like structure. Equality would then be comparing the data `Rc` struct is pointing to, not the pointer itself.

Comment: @NebulaFox that means that you are ok with serialization and deserialization [not being a round-trip](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f22d1685bea7119ff78b2440ca9b6e87).

Comment: I understand now. Going one direction doesn't incur a memory penality, but going back and forth does.